# React Native Image Resizer for iOS

Tags: android, ios, react-native, camera, compression

Is there any possible library in react native to compress the images captures using iOS ?
 we are using https://github.com/bamlab/react-native-image-resizer for compressing image for android. is there any possible ways to compress the images iOS

Comment: Here you may find solution for your issue  :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49305438/how-to-get-thumb-image-from-photolibrary-image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That package works for IOS too.