# How to get thumb image from Photolibrary image?

Tags: ios, iphone, react-native, photo-gallery

Currently i am fetching memory issue because i am loading direct image in Flatlist of React Native. Issue is that due to high resolutions images memory limit reached and app get crashed on iPhone. Is there any way i can fetch direct thumb url like image url (e.g. url: 'assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=5BECA80C-33B3-46A0-AE44-CF28A838CECF&ext=JPG',) ?

Currently i am using 'React-native-photo-framework'.

Comment: Can you please share which library you are using with link?

Comment: Its native iOS library. Is there way to read native thumb image of original image we are fetching?

Comment: Doesn't this answer help you? It looks fairly similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28887638/how-to-get-an-alasset-url-from-a-phasset

Comment: Its same thing its providing me direct image path not a thumb path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i have my own solution for this question. I have tried all ways to resolve but i am not able to resolve it. Lastly i come to know that new Photo Library provide options to fetch resized image but thats what not working with [react-native-photos-framework](https://github.com/olofd/react-native-photos-framework). My native experience will help me to resolve my issue, hope this will help you. [Here](https://www.logisticinfotech.com/blog/react-native-import-resized-image-photo-gallery) is link with detail description and code.

Let me add here code snippets.

Import Native Photo Library

```
#import <Photos/Photos.h>

CGSize retinaSquare = CGSizeMake(600, 600);

PHImageRequestOptions *cropToSquare = [[PHImageRequestOptions alloc] init];
cropToSquare.resizeMode = PHImageRequestOptionsResizeModeExact;
cropToSquare.deliveryMode = PHImageRequestOptionsDeliveryModeOpportunistic;
[cropToSquare setSynchronous:YES];

NSURL *imageurl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"youimagepath"];

PHFetchResult* asset =[PHAsset fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:imageurl, nil] options:nil];

[[PHImageManager defaultManager] requestImageForAsset:(PHAsset *)[asset objectAtIndex:0] targetSize:retinaSquare contentMode:PHImageContentModeAspectFit                                                options:cropToSquare                                          resultHandler:^(UIImage *fetchedImage, NSDictionary *info) {

  NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(fetchedImage,0.65);

  NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
  NSTimeInterval timeStamp = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
  NSString *filePath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.0f.jpg", timeStamp*1000]];
  NSError *error = nil;
  [imageData writeToFile:filePath options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&error];
  NSURL* fileUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
  if(error){
    fileUrl = imageurl;
  }

  NSString *resizedImagePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",fileUrl];

}];
```

Comment: this method will create a lot of new photos on the phone because we are making an in-app gallery

Comment: You can add your own function to delete images once its being uploaded to server. It need to be handle your side or you can use image without saving in your document directory.

Comment: but i want to make only in app gallery and i do not want to upload photo to server

Comment: You can find demo here for that : https://github.com/logisticinfotech/react-native-resize-image

Answer (score 1):

`getAssets` takes a `prepareForSizeDisplay` prop. This uses `PHCachingImageManager` to request images of assets at a specified size.

Example:

```
RNPhotosFramework.getAssets({
    startIndex: 0,
    endIndex: 100,
    prepareForSizeDisplay: Rect(100,100),
    fetchOptions: {
        sourceTypes: ['userLibrary'],
        sortDescriptors: [{
            key: 'creationDate',
            ascending: true,
        }]
    }
}).then((response) => console.log(response.assets));
```

When the user taps the row in your `FlatList`, you can then fetch the full-size asset. Don't fetch the full-size asset until you need to display it.

Comment: its not helpful to me.

Comment: What do you find unhelpful?

Comment: Actually i want direct thumb url. I think iPhone is already storing that thats why its load very smooth in iPhone gallery.

Comment: From the iOS Photos docs: *For faster performance with large numbers of assets—for example, when populating a collection view with thumbnails—the `PHCachingImageManager` subclass adds bulk preloading.* The API I recommended is the one intended for your use case.

Comment: Aaron, I got final solution for this by using native iOS module. Actually there is some issue with RNPhotosFramework, if you set prepareForSizeDisplay: Rect(100,100), then its freezes app without any error. I have tried lots of solution but finally i have created native iOS module and implement that in my code.

Comment: @NileshKikani Good to hear, can you post the code from your solution as a separate answer?

Comment: Yeah sure i will make separate demo here so it will be very useful to others. Actually React Native is not handling photos proper way so its better to use native integration foe better optimisation.